# Excel VBA copy paste loop from one sheet to another when condition is met

Tags: excel, row, conditional-statements, copy-paste

I'm a beginner in VBA. I already checked if the question was asked already but found nothing that fits perfectly and also I failed to modify properly the closest codes I found.

I have a file with raw sales data (around 5,000 items) located in sheet1 column A. In sheet2, I have a table with around 500 data in column A where the duplicated items from the sheet1 have been eliminated. Each of the 500 items were renamed in column B.

I want to create a loop which check for each cell in sheet1 column A if the data is same with one of the data from sheet2 column A. When the condition is met, it then copy paste the adequate cell in column B from sheet2 in the adequate cell in sheet1 column B (i.e. same row). I need the operation to be done for the 500 items.

- Example Sheet 1 (see link: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AiRwDFaSvBNalTb0JOIkq8KxiBKs / expected results in red)

Product Sorting 1

choco
cosme
choco
cosme
cosme
cosme
cosme
choco
choco
cosme
cosme
jam 
cosme
cosme

- Example Sheet2 (see link: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AiRwDFaSvBNalTQlKgDKEJTNLvOU)

Product

choco
cosme
jam

Which refers to column Sorting2 with:

CHO
COS
JAM

- Code written so far

  ```
  Sub sorting()

   Dim Cell As Range
   Dim i As Integer

    For Each Cell In Sheet1.Range("A2:A10000)
     If Cell.Value = Sheet2.Range("A2") Then
     Sheets("Sheet2").Select
     Range("A2").Select
     Selection.copy
     Sheets("Sheet1").Select
     Cell(i,2).Select
     Cell.PasteSpecial
     End If
    Next Cell

  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Can you please provide an example result of what you want - Preferably as excel data screenshots?

Comment: User Advance filter to do so easily.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I created a fake file with similar features and added links to pictures as you requested. I'm a new user and it seems I'm not authorized yet to post pictures directly. I understood with other threads on similar topics an advance filter is not the solution as I need frequent updates in the data base. Maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you just need a vlookup formula in sheet1 column b

Something like in cell B2 sheet1

```
=Vlookup(A2,sheet2!'A1:B500,2,0)
```

Then copy paste it all the way down column b

Looking at you code you aren't setting your variable i to anything, looks like you need to add `i=i+1` at the before your if

I would also remove your select and selection as this can cause error if you click you mouse.
You just need

```
Sheets("sheet2").Range("A2"). copy
```

Instead of

```
    Sheets("sheet2").select
Range("A2").select
    Selection.copy
```

Also shouldn't you be copying B2 as A2 is the value you are matching

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried VLOOKUP, INDEX MATCH and IF few days ago but failed. The problem is I need the same operation to repeat in sheet1 for the 500 cases from sheet2. AFAIK a formula sounds limited to perform this task.

Comment: Happy to help, though looking at your examples I still think vlookup would work (I'm probably missing something). I've looked at your code and added to my answer how i think to fix it. Though i would always say, it's better to do a formula if you can rather then vba, so much easy to maintain and often quicker.